# Share dial up internet with an IPod Touch

Tags: windows-xp, ipod-touch, internet-connection, ad-hoc-network, dial-up

I only have dial up internet access at home.  I'd like to connect to the internet on my laptop and then use that connection for my iPod through Internet Connection Sharing.  I don't have a router.  I'm just trying to do an Ad Hod network from WinXP to iPod.  Is that possible?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>The iPod touch requires a WiFi access point. If you don't have a WiFi router, you won't be able to do it.</del>

UPDATE: If you're using a laptop and it has WiFi, you could share your dial-up connection that way. [Here](http://www.ipodwizard.net/showthread.php?t=46349) is a tutorial.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, maybe because I'm using the PeoplePC dialer?